# Rescaling of y axis on an interactive plot depending on zoom

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, zooming, ggplotly

I have an interactive plot on rshiny and I would like the axes to scale dynamically depending on where user zoomed. I think I can use `scale_y_continuous` for that using dynamic elements for ylim, however then I need to know the lower and upper y value of users current frame (where has been zoomed). Is there a way to achieve this with ggplot/rshiny?

```
require(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title=h4("example", align="center")),
  mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot"))
  )

##server
server <- function(input,output){
  dat<-reactive({
    num<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    let<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I")
    df<-data.frame(num,let)
    df
  })

  output$plot<-renderPlotly({
    gg <- ggplot(dat(),aes(x=let,y=num))+geom_point(aes(colour='red'))
    gg2 <- ggplotly(gg) %>% layout(dragmode="select")
    gg2
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out. It doesn't use plotly, but same general idea. Essentially it filters the data to the brush. Double clicking will return to full extent.

```
require(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title=h4("example", align="center")),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot", brush = brushOpts("brush_p")))
  )

##server
server <- function(input,output){
  dat<-reactive({
    num<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    let<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I")
    df<-data.frame(num,let)
    df
  })

  dat2 <- reactive({
    y_max <- input$brush_p$ymax
    y_min <- input$brush_p$ymin
    if(is.null(y_max)) return(dat())
    dat() %>% filter(num > y_min & num < y_max)
  })

  output$plot<-renderPlot({
    gg <- ggplot(dat2(),aes(x=let,y=num))+geom_point(aes(colour='red'))
    gg
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Created on 2018-08-19 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).